# When trying to post IFormFile[] (array) - Everything is null

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, iformfile

Controller:

```cs
[HttpPost("CreateEmail")]
[Consumes("multipart/form-data")]
public async Task<ApiResponse<Guid>> PostEmailToProcess([FromForm]EmailToProcess email) 
{
    try
    {
        var emailToAdd = new EmailToProcessDto(email);
        emailToAdd.Created = DateTime.Now;

        var emailId = await _emailRepository.PostEmailAsync(emailToAdd);

        foreach (var file in email)
        {
            if (email.IFormFile != null)
            {
                await _contentUploadService.Upload(file, emailId.Data);
            }
        }
// etc
```

EmailToProcess Object:

```cs
public class EmailToProcess
{
    public string From { get; set; }

    public string To { get; set; }

    ...

    public IFormFile[] IFormFile { get; set; }
}
```

When I post an EmailToProcess - All the fields come back with the correct data but the data in the IFormFile property is always null. When I allow it to submit just 1 IFormFile (no array) - then it works fine and nothing nulls

Comment: Not related to your question, but why do you test whether `email.IFormFile != null` for each file? It's always the same `email`. This would seem more logical: `if (email.IFormFile != null)
{
foreach (var file in email)
{
    await _contentUploadService.Upload(file, emailId.Data);
}
}`

Comment: Your correct Oliver, I will change this

Comment: Could you share client code?

Comment: How do you name your html form fields?

Answer (score 1):

- Check your  element. It must be contain enctype attribute and equal than "multipart/form-data".
- If you use FormData object, you must append your props to that model and post it.

You can look at [this](https://gowthamcbe.com/2022/02/28/swagger-with-multipart-formdata-net-core-6/) example.

Comment: So there is no front end interacting with this endpoint, everything goes null when I post an EmailToProcess object on Swagger and when posting from another application

Comment: maybe that example helps you. https://gowthamcbe.com/2022/02/28/swagger-with-multipart-formdata-net-core-6/